# How do I switch off this part of CK editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, richtextbox, ckeditor, config

[image]

How do I switch off this bottom bit? Can't seem to find it in the docs, can do just about everything else...

```
config.??? = false;
```

Answers on a postcard boys and girls.

:D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
```